# Error closing a file with fscanf

Tags: c, file

I'm making a code to encrypt and decrypt a plaintext using the cryptography technique Vigenère Cipher.

The code to encrypt is working fine, but I'm having a problem with my decrypt code.

To decrypt:

I read a file, with the cipher of the plaintext (encoded) and pick an hexadecimal of two digits, make a `XOR` with my key, and it returns me the
original message coded.

The problem is that I'm having a problem after all this process. 
The algorithm works well... it decrypts, but it seems that it have a problem
with the `EOF`, because the code returns me an error after the process and did not let me close the file.

The idea is to save the cipher `XOR` Key in a file:

```
fprintf(fpOut, "%c", ch ^ key[i % KEY_LENGTH]);
```

- The plaintext message is 'Hello!'
- The ctext file contains 'Hello!' XOR Key = e94acd43ce0e
- The dtext file must contains the message Hello again (cipher `XOR` key = message)

My original code (simplified) is this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define KEY_LENGTH 2 // Can be anything from 1 to 13

int main ( void ) {

    unsigned char ch;

    FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
    int i;
    unsigned char key[KEY_LENGTH] = {0xA1, 0x2F};

    fpIn = fopen("ctext.txt", "r");
    fpOut = fopen("dtext.txt", "w");
    i = 0;

    while (fscanf(fpIn, "%02x", &ch) != EOF) {
        printf ("\n Value read: %x", ch);
        if (ch != '\n'){
                ch = ch ^ key[i % KEY_LENGTH];
                i++;
        }
        printf ("\n Value after XOR: %c", ch);
    }

    fclose(fpIn);
    fclose(fpOut);
    return;
}
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: It returns you an error as you should return `0` from `main`. (and declare it as `int main(void)`)

Comment: Can you please try harder to write a question title?

Comment: `unsigned char ch;` --> `unsigned  ch;`

Comment: Next time don't write the whole file before trying to compile. It's like making soup without ever tasting it until the very end.

Comment: Compiled with `-Wall` option gives _warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned char *’_

Comment: "So... after the errors, I removed the save file part and worked only with the XOR process, printing in the screen step by step... trying to see where the code fails. "... _and?_

Comment: @John Hascall Why are you fixing OP's code in the question? It is clearly not the intention of the `edit` button.

Comment: return 0; doesn't change to question or the answer.  It was obviously distracting people from the real question.

Comment: Come on, one person mentioning it doesn't mean "It was obviously distracting people".

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your code with `-Wall` option the following message will be displayed:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:471:5: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned char *’ [-Wformat=]
     while (fscanf(fpIn, "%02x", &ch) != EOF) {
     ^
```

The error is the type of variable passed to `scanf`. You are passing address of a char variable, mostly 8 bits.

`scanf` takes that address as `unsigned int` pointer and write it with `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes.

The first variable declared after `ch` variable is `fpIn`. This variable is overwritten by `scanf` and this is why you cannot close the input file: due to the fact that the pointer is corrupted.